# Angular Table CSS structure with 3 level

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css, user-interface, css-tables

Please see below code, which is running fine.

```html
<div ng-repeat="download in productDownloads"
 class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="cell">
   <strong>{{download.productName}}</strong>
  </div>

 </div>
 <div ng-repeat="release in download.productReleasesList">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="cell">
    {{release.downloadName}}
   </div>

  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="downloadDetail in release.downloadDetailList">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">{{downloadDetail.downloadName}}</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Its giving result in 3 separate lines without any CSS.

I want to display like tree/table with row within row.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the first row before opening the nested ones. 
Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="download in productDownloads"
    class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            <strong>{{download.productName}}</strong>
        </div>
    <div ng-repeat="release in download.productReleasesList">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell">
                {{release.downloadName}}
            </div>

        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="downloadDetail in release.downloadDetailList">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="cell">{{downloadDetail.downloadName}}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still its plan texts only. No table border, coulmns, no row borders and anything

Comment: Still not working.... i want to look like table with border, row border, columns, evrything and whith hierarchy...just like parent->child->child